# Sort from array

Tags: mongodb, typescript, sails.js

I have one json file

var params = permissions.json;

```
[
  {
    "module": "h1", 
    "permission": "h1-menu"
  },
  {
    "module": "h2", 
    "permission": "h2-menu"
  },
  {
    "module": "h3", 
    "permission": "h3-menu"
  },
]
```

In in mongo collection

```
const permissions = await Permissions.find();
[
  {
    "module": "h1", 
    "permission": "h1-menu"
  },
  {
    "module": "h2", 
    "permission": "h2-menu"
  }
]
```

Now i want to create new array from params array which object values not present in permissions array by permission value, after sorting new array i want to creatEach array object by individual in db.

```
const PermissionsResult = await Permissions.createEach(newArray).fetch();
```

OR

How to create newly added permissions in json file to Permissions collection without sorting. This is initialization service of sails js.

```
var permissions_json = require('../../assets/init/permissions.json');
// Find permissions
  const permissions = await Permissions.find();
  if (permissions && permissions.length > 0) {
    return permissions;
  }
  const params = permissions_json;
  // Create permissions as per json data
  const PermissionsResult = await Permissions.createEach(params).fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless Mongo has JSON-specific functions for union and join and whatnot, you'll be doing this in Javascript.

1. Create an array of the `permission` field's values in the mongo collection.
2. Loop through the test values (your `params` var).
3. If a test value isn't in the array of key values, add the relevant entry from `params` to a `createMe` array.
4. Sort `createMe`, then create the records.

Alternatively, could you not simply sort your `params` array, and then do Waterline's [findOrCreate() method](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/find-or-create)?